# Blank page on loading of php file

Tags: php

When I go to load this in the browser, nothing is displayed. If I comment out the last line it works fine. I thought that if the last line was causing some type of error it would be reported, rather than nothing happening.

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "hello"
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/svn_log.xml')
?>
```

Comment: Missing two ending/closing semi-colons. The one for `echo "hello"` is the most important one.

Comment: if you had error checking and display ON you would see the error and not a blank page.

Comment: as best I can tell I've turned them on. it's apache hosted so I went in and changed the php.ini file so they would be on

Comment: what does `phpinfo()` say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing two ending/closing semi-colons.

The one for `echo "hello"` is the most important one.

It's good practice to finish all lines with semi-colons.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "hello";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/svn_log.xml');
?>
```